# This is about pyomo and specifically the glpk solver, is there anyway to set the max iteration for glpk in pyomo?

Tags: pyomo, glpk

For example I found a solution in matlab which is “options.glpk.itlim" - is there something similar to this ?

Comment: I don't see anything in the glpk options for iteration limit.  Setting the *time* limit is much more common, and easy to do.

Comment: 1. Specify solver: `solver = pe.SolverFactory('glpk')`

2. Specify solver options: `solver.options['tmlim'] = 100  # limit solving time to 100sec`